# Should i Import appcompact_v7 to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-studio-import

I'm porting from eclipse to android studio, do I need to import appcompat_v7 from my existing eclipse project into android studio?

Comment: Impossible to tell. Depends on your code and if you're using the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in Android's Support Library Overview, it is considered good practice to include the support library by default because of the large diversity of devices and the fragmentation that exists between the different versions of Android (and thus, of the provided APIs).

This is the reason why Android code templates tools included in Android Studio through the Android Development Tools (ADT) integrate them by default.

An example would be the ability of using the Fragment API which appears on API 11 (Android 3.0 Honeycomb) on a device that runs an older version of this system. Or the newer RecyclerView which was introduced in API 21 (Android 5.0 Lollipop) can be used on pre-lollipop devices with the user of appcompact.

It is also to be noted that you can deactivate automatic inclusion of the Support Library by default.

**To import a project to Android Studio:**

1. Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
2. From the Android Studio menu select File > New > Import Project.
3. Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.
4. Select the destination folder and click Next.
5. Select the import options and click Finish.

The import process prompts to migrate any library and project dependencies to Android Studio, and add the dependency declarations to the build.gradle file. The import process also replaces any well-known source libraries, binary libraries, and JAR files that have known Maven coordinates with Maven dependencies, so you no longer need to maintain these dependencies manually. The import options also allow you to enter your workspace directory and any actual path maps to handle any unresolved relative paths, path variables, and linked resource references.

6. Android Studio imports the app and displays the project import summary. Review the summary for details about the project restructuring and the import process.

After importing the project from Eclipse ADT to the new Android Studio project and module structure, each app module folder in Android Studio contains the complete source set for that module, including the src/main and src/androidTest directories, resources, build file, and Android manifest. Before starting app development, you should resolve any issues shown in the project import summary to make sure the project re-structuring and import process completed properly.

The process is changed frequently so the text above will probably be outdated very soon whilst the link below will be updated so the link is you're best bet. The link also provides pictures to help aid the process.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score -1):

You should be written your build.gradle file.

This is script.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'           //Support Library
}
```

Comment: Can you Please Explain more.. How do i go about it.

Comment: He says "should I", not "how can I"